# Displaying folder contents without extensions as links

Tags: php

I am dealing with a very large amount of files and I am trying to output the directory contents into a table without the extension at the end and in a link format so the files can be downloaded. The problem is it also strips the extension off the href part as well. I am not a coder just decent at looking stuff up sometimes and then trying to make it work. How do I make the filename in the actual link still have the extension but not in the display text on the page?

Here is my code which outputs correctly and shows the table correctly. Unfortunately I had to put .mp3 back in there to make it function correctly.

```
<?php
   $files = glob('audio/2008/*.*');
   foreach($files as $file) {
   if (! is_dir($file)) {
   $file = pathinfo($file);
    echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><a href='audio/2008/" . $file['filename'] .  ".mp3'>" . $file['filename'] . "</a></div>";
    }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Use `$file['basename']` in the link. This will return the file name and extension too. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php#refsect1-function.pathinfo-examples

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: np - you can mark @Bojan's answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$file['basename']` instead of `$file['filename']` in your `href`

```
<?php
   $files = glob('audio/2008/*.*');
   foreach($files as $file) {
   if (! is_dir($file)) {
   $file = pathinfo($file);
    echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'><a href='audio/2008/" . $file['basename'].'>" . $file['filename'] . "</a></div>";
    }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Man I love you. Thank you so much. That was almost too easy lol.

Comment: @CameronFisher No problem, please accept the answer when you can

Comment: It finally let me. Thanks agin!